# HashMap serialization in Realm (mobile database)

Tags: dictionary, serialization, collections, hashmap, realm

We would like to use Realm mobile database, but couldn't find any reference about how do you read and write a **HashMap** (Map/Dictionary in Apple languages) or any other **Collection** type field of your RealmObject subclass?

Is there a way to make Realm handle these fields like primitive type fields for serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct support for anything but `List` in Realm right now. One workaround is to define your own tuple as a model class and operate on that instead. You can specify your key to be a primary key so that will ensure uniqueness.